# jenkins - ant svn tasks getting stuck indefinitely

Tags: java, svn, ant, jenkins

As part of build automation, we are running various ant tasks using jenkins. When the build script encounters any ant svn tasks, we are observing unknown behaviour where the build process gets stuck indefinitely until we abort the same with "started" message of the ant svn task. For example, for a ant svn mkdir task, below is the output shown in jenkins,

```
    Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Create Release
[scripts] $ /opt/apps/common/ABE/ant/bin/ant -file build.xml ******** -Dsvn.user=anab -Dpackage.todeploy=TestPackage -Dsvn.release.source.revison=HEAD -Denv=vm01 -Drelease.name=R2.2.1 create-release-vcs
Buildfile: /opt/apps/build-automation/src/com/india/buildtools/scripts/build.xml

-check:

create-release-vcs:

-check:

-check-svn-properties:

-create-svn-release-tag:
     [echo] **************************************
     [echo] Create relase tag for project [${build.project.id}]
     [echo] 
     [echo] BUILD-ID: ${build.id}
     [echo] BRANCH: ${build.branch.name}
     [echo] VERSION: 9.5
     [echo] **************************************
     [echo] Tagging Release ${svn.release.name}...
     [echo] **************************************
      [svn] <Mkdir> started ...
```

**EDIT**

**Build Script**

```
<antcontrib:trycatch>
            <try>
                <svn username="${svn.user}" password="${svn.password}" javahl="true"
                    failonerror="true">
                    <mkdir url="${svn.packages.release.destination}/${release.name}"
                        message="Creating release tag directory ${release.name}" />
                </svn>
            </try>
            <catch>
                <fail
                    message="Invalid Tag name or release tag directory [${svn.packages.release.destination}/${release.name}] already exists." />
            </catch>
</antcontrib:trycatch>
```

**EDIT 2**

I have launched some jobs and left them running. Finally, for a copy task it failed with below log,

```
    [svn] <Copy> started ...
      [svn] svn: connection refused by the server
      [svn] svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/Project/Codebase/ui-modules/TestUI-portlet'
      [svn] svn: connection refused by the server
      [svn] svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/Project/Codebase/ui-modules/TestUI-portlet'
      [svn] Connection timed out
      [svn] <Copy> failed !

BUILD FAILED
/opt/apps/ui-build-automation/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0/SVNSCripts/build.xml:26: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/apps/ui-build-automation/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0/SVNSCripts/build-base.xml:58: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/apps/ui-build-automation/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0/SVNSCripts/build-base.xml:45: Can't copy

Total time: 876 minutes 49 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any help to pin point the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Permission to create/write folders are presented for user that is running task?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the Ant code containing the `MkDir` call.

Comment: @PawełGłowacz I have necessary permissions in place for directory creation in the SVN. Also I am able to run the same mkdir command through unix command line as well to create the directory successfully.

Comment: @ChadNouis: I have posted the build script requested.